# Add UIBezierPath to UIView and rotate device, the path doesn't update its position

Tags: ios, swift2, uibezierpath

I'm trying to add an ovalPath to my view as per below.

```
 let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width*0.5 - 280.5*0.5, y: 276.5, width: 280.5, height: 214.5))
        let ovalShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        ovalShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
        ovalShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor
        ovalShapeLayer.lineWidth = 1.5
        ovalShapeLayer.path = ovalPath.CGPath

        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(ovalShapeLayer, atIndex: 1)
```

When I rotate the device the path doesn't update its position.

If I put this on `viewDidLayoutSubviews` the it gets called twice.

Thanks.